# Ripple animation for android layout

Tags: java, android, flutter

The below code is applicable for layout whereas it's not supported for buttons why is that so

Tried of using this code in the button

```
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: Flutter do not use native widget. Flutter has its own widgets
Inkwell is the ripple animation button https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html

Comment: If you're using `RaisedButton` you can specify `splashColor` property.